# Check if a student has passed a class

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list/dictionary within a dictionary, and I want to check if a specific person has passed the subject or not. The dictionary looks like this:

```
students = {
'Peter': ['Economy', {'PRO100': 'B', 'PRO110': 'C', 'DAT130': F}], 
'James': ['Psychology', {'MAT120': C, 'PRO100': B, 'DAT120': A}]
}
```

A is the best grade, and F is failed. 'Economy' and 'Psychology' shows which department the subjects belongs to.

I want a function like this:

```
def check(student, subject)
```

where I can check passed/failed as this:

```
check('Peter', 'PRO100')
>>> True
check('Peter', 'DAT130')
>>> False
```

I think I can use a for-loop within the function, but I don't know how...

Comment: What have you tried, do you have some code which does not work correctly we can help with? At the moment it looks like you want someone to write all the code for you. Please read the help section on [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Read about [dictionaries](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) and try implementing accordingly. If you face any issue in doing so then post your code here and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your code :

```py
students = {
    'Peter': [
        'Economy', {
            'PRO100': 'B', 
            'PRO110': 'C', 
            'DAT130': 'F'
        }
    ], 
    'James': [
        'Psychology', {
            'MAT120': 'C', 
            'PRO100': 'B', 
            'DAT120': 'A'
        }
    ]
}

good_grades = ['A', 'B', 'C']
bad_grades = ['D', 'E', 'F']

def check(student, subject):
    for subjects in students[student]:
        subjectList = subjects
    
    for grade in subjectList:
        if grade == subject:
            if subjectList[grade] in good_grades:
                return True
            if subjectList[grade] in bad_grades:
                return False
            
    return 'Not Found'
    
    
check('Peter', 'PRO100')
```

**Examples :**

```py
check('Peter', 'DAT130')
False
```

```py
check('James', 'DAT120')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
students = {
'Peter': ['Economy', {'PRO100': 'B', 'PRO110': 'C', 'DAT130': 'F'}], 
'James': ['Psychology', {'MAT120': 'C', 'PRO100': 'B', 'DAT120': 'A'}]
}

passed_grades = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def check(student, subject):
    if students[student][1][subject] in passed_grades:
        return True
    return False
```